# What does each statistic do?

Tags: pyre

Each character in Pyre has stats. Things like Presence and hope (I think there are 2 others, but can't remember them off the top of my head).

So what does every stat do?

PS: I think presence is the size of the 'elimination zone' of your character, but I have no clue what hope does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 4 stats: Glory, Quickness, Presence and Hope.

Glory determines how much damage you deal when jumping into the enemy pyre, or the max dmg of your throw.

Quickness is, as the name suggests, how fast the character moves.

Presence is just as you said - determines the killzone aura of your character.

Hope determines how fast the character 'respawns' after being banished by the enemy.